# Rails : Rake Test:functionals cannot access DB (Sqlite3 on winXP)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, sqlite, rubygems, rake

I am unable to run rake test:functionals with SQLite3, it gives me this error :

```
rake aborted!
Permission denied - db/test.sqlite

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My setup is on Windows XP.
Tests were working a few weeks ago.
Rails 2.3.2, Rake 0.8.7, sqlite3-ruby 1.2.5 gems

I am using Netbeans for development, but even when it's close I cannot run the test from a command prompt.

I also checked that no handles to test.sqlite are open (through the sysinternals task manager).

I checked the permissions, they are ok.

I tried to delete the file and recreate it, or copy to another filename without any luck either.

I tried running the command as soon as my computer is booted.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: other commands like rake db:migrate or purge or clone are working on this database. It's only test:functionals which fails.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue. For me, it was caused by me having my rails console opened in a test environment. Closed my session and it no longer threw the error.

Answer (score 2):

Very, very similar behavior on my part: Windows XP, SQLite3, Rails 2.3.4, Rake 0.8.7, Ruby 1.8.6

> rake test

works (but I don't believe it's actually running the unit test)

> rake test:units

and

> rake test:functionals

both fail with a "Permission denied - db/test.sqlite3"
With --trace enabled the specific error occurs at ../rails-2.3.4/lib/task/databases.rake:370 at a line that reads "File.delete(dbfile) if File.exist?(dbfile)

So... long story short... I commented it out.

This is NOT a fix, but it was enough of a hack to get the tests to work for me.

Comment: That line seems to be the problem for me too... not sure what to do about it though!

Answer (score 1):

If you're running under Cygwin, try running this on your database files:

```
chmod 777 <your-files>
```

Cygwin can become confused about what permissions should be applied.

Yes I know these permissions are ridiculous, but so is Cygwin sometimes...

Comment: No I'm running under Windows. Tried it anyway, and not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just a punt, but have you tried changing the path in `config/database.yml` to

```
database: db\test.sqlite3
```

i.e. a backslash instead of a forwardslash.  Or even a full dos style path.  Issue could be related to this https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4153-dbcreate-cannot-open-database-for-sqlite3-on-windows-with-cygwin

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue as well and I found the culprit to be an initializer in an engine that was querying the database during environment load and preventing the sqlite3 file from being deleted:

```
module Frame
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Frame

    # Engine initializer causing the problem.
    initializer "frame.wrap_parameters" do
      ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
        if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)

          # This is the problem line,  Link is a model and Link.attribute_names
          # is accessing the DB.
          wrap_parameters Link, include: Link.attribute_names + [:parent_id]

        end 
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I fixed it by removing the DB requirement from the intializer.

The weird thing about the issue was that the tests would work when running them for the engine, but not when the engine was mounted in a project, it would cause all of the project's tests to fail.